# How to Unmarshal the pair values in an nested array by json for Golang

Tags: go

The JSON data like the following:

```
{"xxx_xxx":{"asks":[[0.00000315,1022.53968253],[0.00000328,200],[0.00000329,181.70008541]],"bids":[[0.00000254,2685.36319716],[0.00000253,600],[0.0000025,1000]]}}
```

the struct as:

```
type Depth struct {
    XXX_XXX struct {
        Asks []struct {
            Num0 float64 `json:"0"`
            Num1 float64 `json:"1"`
        } `json:"asks"`
        Bids []struct {
            Num0 float64 `json:"0"`
            Num1 float64 `json:"1"`
        } `json:"bids"`
    } `json:"xxx_xxx"`
}
```

when try to map in go-lang as following:

```
json.Unmarshal(r, &depth)
```

will get all zero arrays like following:

```
{{[{0 0} {0 0} {0 0} ] [{0 0} {0 0} {0 0} ]}}
```

It does not come up the result as I expected.
How to solve this problem?

HERE is the code on playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/wxFV6Mv26t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asks and bids are array types not struct types.

Here is a working [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/wbx_5pplNl)

Below is an example that adds a `Nums` type that has a `One` and `Two` method you can use since those seem to be the format you are expecting. You could add some error checking in these methods to ensure the format is correct too.,

```
type Depth struct {
    XXX XXX `json:"xxx_xxx"`
}

type XXX struct {
    Asks []Nums `json:"asks"`
    Bids []Nums `json:"bids"`
}

type Nums []float64

func (n Nums) One() float64 {
    if len(n) > 0 {
         return n[0]
    }
    return 0
}

func (n Nums) Two() float64 {
    if len(n) > 1 {
        return n[1]
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: thanks , I guess that's the answer. you saved my ton of time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because your arrays are structs in Go, but your JSON has arrays of arrays, which aren't the same. You'd want to change `[0.00000315,1022.53968253]` to `{"0": ##, "1": ##}`, so on and so forth.

Or, you can have a separate Go struct where Asks is an array of arrays of float64s, etc., but this would be less type safe since arrays could have more or less than 2 elements.

Now, in JS, array elements can be referenced by numerical keys and arrays can be treated as objects, but in JSON, objects and arrays are distinct.

EDIT: add quotations around key names, as specified by the comment below. My mistake :)

Comment: thanks your reply, however, I am not able to change the source json file.

Comment: @temple got it - then, the other answer is the way to go. you'll be unmarshaling arrays of arrays of float64s. you can of course use that code for unmarshaling and then use the data to populate a more type-safe structure, and weed out any invalid data (e.g. data that has less than or more than 2 items in an ask/bid)