# type interface {} does not support indexing

Tags: go

I want to get values from `bid`.
I've already tried `data.(map[string]interface{})` but It did not work.

when I tried, It says:

> "interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}"

Please help me...

This is my code.

```
    url := "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=RENBTC"
    a, _ := http.Get(url)
    e, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(a.Body)

    var data map[string]interface{}

    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(e), &data)
    bid := data["bids"]
    fmt.Println(bid[0])
```

[image: tooltip]

Comment: If the error says _"interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}"_ then maybe try to type-assert a `[]interface {}` value and not a map, e.g. `bid.([]interface{})[0]`.

Comment: See related questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952116/get-value-of-struct-with-interfaces/48952864#48952864), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892984/how-to-unmarshal-the-pair-values-in-an-nested-array-by-json-for-golang), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297289/unmarshaling-json-into-a-type).

Comment: There's a dozen other questions containing this exact error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+%22type+interface+%7B%7D+does+not+support+indexing%22 (and many dozens more with relevant answers)

Answer (score 5):

You need **type assertion**  `bid, ok := data["bids"].([]interface{})`
See: [Explain Type Assertions in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816843/explain-type-assertions-in-go)

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=RENBTC"
    a, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(a.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var data map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(buf), &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bid, ok := data["bids"].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("not ok")
    }

    s, ok := bid[0].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("not ok")
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
[0.00000603 5122.00000000]
```

Comment: For newbies like me: see the `json.Unmarshal` doc, and you'll understand why this code works. *"To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:  []interface{}, for JSON arrays /  map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects / ......."*